# Do http response packets start getting sent to caller before all middleware execution is complete? (aspnetcore)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have the following setup -> An Azure API Management layer calling in to a web api hosted on Service Fabric in a container. The web API runs on asp netcore using MVC. We have a lot of middlewares in our code and we measure the latency of the request in each. We also measure the latency of the request at the caller (Azure API Management layer).

What we are seeing is that the latency measured in the last middleware is 10 seconds for some calls while the same latency measures in both the second last middleware AND the higher Azure API Management layer is 200ms. That is a huge difference. The reason provided was that API Management layer starts measuring the end time latency of a request as soon as it gets the first packet.

**Is it possible for an Http Request to start sending packets to the caller even before all middlewares have finished executing?**

Comment: no you can't. it is not supported in this way. Don't call next.Invoke after the response has been sent to the client. Changes to HttpResponse after the response has started throw an exception. For example, changes such as setting headers and a status code throw an exception. Writing to the response body after calling next:

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. That is what I would expect. However, the explanation given to us has been that the first packet hits our higher layer earlier than the whole middleware code has finished processing, which seems improbable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for middleware to start writing response.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                $"Hello {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName}");
            // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
            await next();
        });

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            //this is just starting, yet the response already started
            //and the current culture info change is not used in the response.
            var cultureQuery = context.Request.Query["culture"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureQuery))
            {
                var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureQuery);

                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Where the response to be sent or not immediately depends on HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput value. When it is true, the next in line middleware may clear the buffer and start all over again. If it is false the data is sent to the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible, in fact we Make it possible when we make Middlewares.

here is a custom middleware:

```
public class MyCustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        //do sth

        //line below writes response
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Hello");

        //do sth

        //line below passes request to next middleware
        await _next(httpContext);

        //do sth
    }
}
```

Notice that you can omit both `await context.Response.WriteAsync(xxx);` and `await _next(httpContext);`

If you omit `await _next(httpContext);` the request won't be passed to next middleware.

A Middleware can start to respond the request and then it can decide to pass the request to the next Middleware or not.
If a Middleware tries to write to response body of already responded request using `Response.WriteAsync()`, an exception will occur.

If we are going to use Middlewares writed by others, We must know about them.

[Write Custome ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
page shows how to create Middlewares in more details.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the answer completely. How can a middleware send response packets out even though the higher middlewares are yet to execute?